# But I DID override that abstract method

Tags: java, abstract-class

I must be an idiot, but I'm just not getting what my error is here.

```
final class EmptyBench extends MicroBench {
    long doIterations(long numIterations) throws InterruptedException {
        return numIterations;
    }
}
```

This extends the class MicroBench containing this declaration:

```
abstract long doIterations(long numIterations) throws InterruptedException;
```

I get this error:

```
EmptyBench.java:6: error: EmptyBench is not abstract and does not override abstract method doIterations(long) in MicroBench
```

There are no generics in sight, no change in return types, no change in the throws clause.  Can someone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Looks really strange. Are you sure you're pointing to the right class and that it is indeed the same signature (and by same signature I also mean if the same characters are used)?

Comment: You are not compiling the code you are looking at.

Comment: maybe it's an access modifier issue? what packages are the classes in?

Comment: Is this the only abstract method in MicroBench ? Also, always use the `@Override` annotation to ensure you are overriding a method of your superclass.

Comment: You are probably not in the same package and this method is package protected

Comment: Check your import section, are you importing the class you really wanted to import? Also, once in a while the IDE might mess up automatic compilation, showing errors where there are none. Try rebuilding the entire project.

Comment: Like @shlomi33 said, `doIterations` has no access modifier so it's package protected by default. Either make the method public or have EmptyBench be in the same package as MicroBench.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using these classes, I can reproduce the problem:

```
package a;

public abstract class A {
    abstract void method();
}
```

and

```
package b;

import a.A;

public final class B extends A {
    void method() {}
}
```

However, my IDE (Eclipse) gave me a different error message, so YMMV:

> This class must implement the inherited abstract method A.method(), but cannot override it since it is not visible from B. Either make the type abstract or make the inherited method visible

I don't have anything to add to this error message, except that, if you don't control the `MicroBench` class, you're out of luck.

As a side note, if `B` was abstract instead of final, then you could create a class `a.C extends b.B` that in turn would be able to implement `a.A.method()`

Comment: WOW.  You rock.  Thanks a million.

Comment: Could you tell us if/how you solved the problem? did you move the classes to the same package, or make the method public, or something else?

Comment: I made the abstract method protected.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the signature, and always use `@Override` - your IDE might even help with autocompletion. Are you sure you are extending the right MicroBench; maybe you have several versions in different packages?

```
@Override
public long doIterations(long numIterations) throws InterruptedException {
```

BTW most IDEs let you generate code for overriding a method, maybe at the error icon in the margin / implement all abstract methods.

Comment: `@Override` will make the compiler verify that the method is indeed overriding, but it won't make it override a method it wouldn't otherwise be overriding.

Comment: @SillyFreak Yes but it discovers errors in the signature like `actionPérformed(ActionEvent)` (`é`), and should help in autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

There is another reason why this could be happening. Java doesn't always like extending classes outside of a package. In eclipse, if you have package 1 that contains MicroBench, and package 2 that contains EmptyBench, you will not be able to extend that MicroBench class due to package permissions.